# Questions list / checklist to ask before buying a source code?

Tags: source-code, code-analysis, code-review

I intend to buy a PHP source code from one company. Since i have plans to **scale** and improve the code afterwards it is important for me to know about software architecture.
Is there some kind of a checklist or questions list before buying a source code that will help me to understand what to expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really in scope here but a few things to look for:

1. The **EXACT** licence terms are you allowed to produce and sell your own products based on it, etc.
2. The **origin** - you can hit big problems if it turns out you have been sold code that was, *partly or fully,* originally GPL or was someone elses code.
3. **Test** Suite coverage - Should be 100%
4. **Portability** & dependencies on specific versions of tools, OS, Libraries, etc.
5. Coding **Standards**
6. **Documentation** and commenting
7. Mondularity & **structure**
8. Maintenance & Support contract, if any.

Comment: @dFine - Comes from having seen it go wrong too many times in various languages. That is why I tend to go for FOSS code if the licences can be worked out.